# SSH stealing files from client?

Tags: ssh, server

Is it technically possible for a ssh server to steal files from a connected client?.

Comment: Is SSH the real issue? Would your question be as relevant if you were asking about telnet, for instance?

Comment: From how you pose the question: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

When the client implements the SSH protocol correctly, this should not be possible.

However, you can never rule out a bug in the client which can be exploited by a malicious server to obtain information from the client.

Comment: What about tunneling over SSH?

Comment: @raz same situation, plus any possible vulnerabilities in the application you tunnel.